# Cadastrar registro no banco de dados e tratar esses dados na mesma pagina depois do registro

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho que fazer um script que quando eu coloco o email na textarea ele cadastra no banco e automaticamente depois do registro ele começa a executar o script que puxa as imagem pelo  email.

Já fiz a parte de salvar no banco e de consultar a foto pelo email , porém tenho que entrar no link cadastrar.php e depois no pega.php.

Queria fazer uma forma que ao cadastrar a lista de emails ele automaticamente chamasse o arquivo pega.php e exibisse os resultado na página de acordo com o registro do banco de dados sem ter que sair da página.

Quero fazer tudo em uma pagina só: cadastrar e automaticamente depois do registro ao banco ele executar o script sem sair da pagina.

Segue o código:

```
    <?php

session_start();

if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) {

  $hash = md5( implode( $_POST ) );

  if( isset( $_SESSION['hash'] ) && $_SESSION['hash'] == $hash ) {

    // Refresh! Não faz nada ou re-exibe o formulário preenchido

  } else {

    $_SESSION['hash']  = $request;

    // Submissão legítima! Insere ;)
  }
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>By WeeennderT -</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .x {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="s1.php">
    <p>
      <label for="x"></label>
      <textarea name="x" id="x" cols="150" rows="5"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p class="x">Os dados devem esta dessa forma email:senha<br />
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Enviar" />
    </p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>


    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
  die('Não conseguiu conectar' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('painel_central', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Não pode selecionar o banco ' . mysql_error());
}

if ($_POST) {
$x = $_POST ['x'];
$erro = 0;
if (empty($x)) {

  echo "Por favor, adiciona sua lista.";

}
foreach (explode("\n", $x) as $item)
{
  $x = explode(":", $item);

}

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT into mercadolivre(login,senha) VALUES ( '".$x[0]."', '".$x[1]."');") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query($sql);

}

// 
?>
```

depois de inserir quero chamar a página que testa os valores se foi logado ou não.

Comment: tente usar um redirect direto para a pagina pega.php?=iddaultimacasdastrada

Comment: está um pouco vago, poderia postar seu código e elaborar melhor seu problema ?

Comment: Editei a minha pergunta , o que quero e depois de inserir o registro no texarea ele automaticamente já ir até a pagina onde irar retornar os retorno do login cadatrado no banco de dados , quero fazer sem o usuário sair da pagina do formulário se eu abir a pagina direto depois de inserir funciona , mais quero que depois que inseri já chama automático.